# If JavaScript doesn't have getters for unknown properties, how does the following work in mongo db console?

Tags: javascript

As I browsed through stackoverflow, I found there is no such universal getter like php has it. But, the following works in MongoDB console: `db.mycollection.find()` when mycollection is not even defined. So, how does it gets accessed?

PS: 'works' means that it doesn't give any error and returns 0 results as if the db already had the property called 'mycollection'. Note. Mine is a js question unrelated to mongodb concepts.

Comment: What do you mean it works, are you claiming to get documents back without even defining a collection and putting something into the DB

Comment: Nothing happens, what do you even mean by that?

Comment: By 'works' I assume you mean, it doesn't error, and returns 0 results. And the answer to 'why' that happens is probably because mongo handles the error 'gracefully'

Comment: @Jacques. Yes. Cab we do that in code too?

Comment: Technically, it has nothing to do with getters, but you can use a try/catch/finally block if you like. Unless you tell the code to output an error in the catch block, it will silently fail. Terrible for performance tho: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: In this case, it probably as easy as `if ( ! mycollection in db ) return 0;`

Comment: @adeneo That would work, but it would output a 0 in the console (in the OPs example) You could simply just `return`

Comment: @Jacques . It has performance issues means we should not use this technique on server side for ex. to create handy nodejs libraries. Will keep that in mind. Thanks for info.

Comment: It's not something that should not be used, it's something that should not be *overly* used.

Answer (score 2):

Mongo Shell has a [Javascript API](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/). This cannot be considered a pure Javascript console with ECMA standards implemented.

Your queries in the shell are handled by this API - not by Javascript. So, the behavior is very well non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

No idea about what MongoDB does. However, your premise is false.

JavaScript (ES6) has getters for unknown properties, if you use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects.

For example:

```
var db = new Proxy(()=>0, {
  get(target, property, receiver) { // Trap for getting property values
    return target[property] || receiver;
  }
});
'mycollection' in db; // false -- there is no such property
db.mycollection.find(); // 0 -- but accessing it returns a value
```

Comment: ES2015 (6) is great, but based on the OPs question, I doubt (s)he's delved into it thus far. although, (s)he should.

Comment: Which will be really nice in a year or so, when Proxy is actually supported somewhere *(other than the latest Firefox)*

Comment: Firefox 18 is three years old, but it sure says that *(even if I think that's wrong)*? Anyway, Firefox and the latest Edge are the only ones supporting Proxy atm, Node does not support it, and it doesn't look like Babel or Traceur does either

Comment: I have enabled the hidden javascript features(chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony) in chrome but even then it says "Proxy not defined" Mine is  Version  47.